# Django static CSS for page not being found (development)

Tags: html, css, django, static, django-templates

**This is my project settings**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

**HTML file**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "css/scrolling-nav.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Here is my project directory layout:**

https://app.box.com/s/zurax1ytxt71jhi8ieaq

I thought I had set this up perfectly, but while my template html renders, the CSS/JS doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What about your http server config?

Answer (score 1):

my answer is based on your project directory layout.

remove

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
```

and change **STATICFILES_DIRS** like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Even with these, the CSS still doesn't seem to render. Also when requesting the url http://0.0.0.0:5000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css, I receive a 404 not found error. Any ideas?